# Watch goes blank on refresh

Tags: bash, watch

I'm running the following command in watch. Works for the first one but subsequent ones go blank

```
watch diff <(pacman -Q) <(ssh kate "pacman -Q")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
watch 'bash -c "diff <(pacman -Q) <(ssh kate \"pacman -Q\")"'
```

Comment: Looks good. I guess watch is loading sh and not bash or something along those lines?

Comment: in your line, the input redirectors are quickly resolved to file descriptors. at the second run the pacman commands are not executed again so the descriptors are empty.